# Internal Server Error while import js plugin in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, froala

when i import `froala-editor/js/plugins.pkgd.min.js` in _app.js file for `react-froala-wysiwyg` config, i get `Internal Server Error`

[image]

Comment: What does your terminal say for this request? Paste the error stack.

Comment: error - ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at node_modules\froala-editor\js\froala_editor.min.js:7:414
    at node_modules\froala-editor\js\froala_editor.min.js:7:84
    at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\froala-editor\js\froala_editor.min.js:7:155)